# Unable to switch into third window - Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation, test-automation-framework

I'm using below code to switch into windows :

```
    Set<String> handle=driver.getWindowHandles();
    System.out.println(handle);
    Iterator<String> it=handle.iterator();

    String parent=it.next();
    System.out.println("parent window =" +parent);
    String child=it.next();

    System.out.println("second child window =" +child);
    driver.switchTo().window(child);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"fixHeader\"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/a/span")).click();

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    String child2=it.next();
    System.out.println("Third child window =" +child2);
    driver.switchTo().window(child2);
```

But getting below exception :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to
>   locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"stylenumberH"}

Comment: getting Nosuchelement exception

Comment: Welcome to SQA. Which line of your code is throwing the exception?

Comment: from string child 2=it.next()  getting console result as                                                                     
 parent window =CDwindow-32BE03A3EEB4936887DAFA09ACFE1569
second child window =CDwindow-A3D0A7BCC9DAD738BFB5C3BDCA2C97BB
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"stylenumberH"}

Comment: It is not related to opening third child window. The exception is usually thrown by `findElement()` method when it cannot find a matching element in your page. This particular one show there is no element with id "stylenumberH". However, in your code there's no such selector, because you use only XPath selector. It looks like the code you pasted here is different than the one you executed :-)

Comment: @dziecio Getting Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(Unknown Source)

Comment: What is the value of `handle.size()`? Can you print it after first line and paste it here? The problem you mention suggests you want to access 3rd window but there are only two windows in the list of handles.

Comment: @dziecio 2 is the value come after putting handle.size

Answer (score 1):

This function is for switching from 2nd window to 3rd window.

```
public static void switchTo_Third_Window(){

 Set<String> lastWindow = driver.getWindowHandles();
 try {
 int l = lastWindow.size() - 1;

 int inc = -1;
 for (String win : lastWindow) {

 inc++;

 if (inc == l) {
 driver.switchTo().window(win);

 driver.manage().window().maximize();

 System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

 }

 }
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {


 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Used below code to switch into the windows :

```
//Get current window 
String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

//Get all opened windows list
ArrayList tabs = new ArrayList (driver.getWindowHandles());

// print the count of windows
System.out.println(tabs.size());

//Now you can switch into desired window in your case you want to switch into 3rd one so you have to pass the index 2 as it started from 0
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(2));

// now perform the click 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"fixHeader\"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/a/span")).click();

Thread.sleep(3000);

//Switch back to original window
driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);
```

Comment: hi getting indexoutofbound exception ,want to make consoler to switch to second child window.scenario is on click of parent window--->child window come---->then on click on child window--->another grand child window display

Comment: can you share the site URL

Comment: first you have to switch into child window then click and then again switch into last window

Comment: Yes this is scenario.URL is use internally .vpn protected

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code. You will be able to switch to the new window.

```
    String Parent_Window = driver.getWindowHandle();
    Set<String> AllWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for (String Child : AllWindows) {
        if (!Parent_Window.equalsIgnoreCase(Child)) {
                driver.switchTo().window(Child);
```

Comment: Try this code with your respective condition. This is working fine on 2 windows at a time.